# Crop and scale a specific region of an image using CSS (responsively)

Tags: html, css, scale, crop, fluid-layout

I'd like to show the user a specific part of an image. Ideally, I'd be able to crop the image on the server, but I'm unable to do so for this application. I'd like a solution that appeared to the user as if the image were in fact cropped on the server, such that it could scale properly as its containing elements got bigger or smaller.

Concretely, say my image is 200px wide by 300px high, and I'd like to show the region of the image that goes in x from 0px to 200px, and in y from 75px to 225px. Therefore I'd want an 'effective image' of size 200px wide by 150px high.

I'm assuming that this will involve background-position and size, but I'm unable to figure out how to use these such that I can:

1. Show ONLY the desired region of the image.
2. Can be placed in a container with a fluid width (e.g. width: 50%) and have the size change accordingly.

I've included an example of what I've tried so far here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/maCvd

The example has the uncropped image, scaling to the size of its container, which is 75% of 100px. It also shows what I'd like to effectively get out of the CSS -- something equivalent to the physically cropped image, which can also scale to the size of its parent.

It shows my attempt at using background-size, which as you can see, does not scale to the size of its parent.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.** See also: Stack Overflow question checklist.

Comment: You can do it with a background image such as this but without knowing what you're trying to it's hard to be more specific.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for the pointers. I'm updating my post right now with more details and an example.

Answer (score 0):

The only way i can think of doing this is using the `clip` property. Unfortunately, this can only be applied to **inline** images that are **positioned absolutely**.

So, based on the question:

[**Codepen Example**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/wcItg)

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="clipper" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-200-300-8.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  width:50%;
  height:350px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border:1px solid grey;
  position: relative;   
}

.clipper {
  position: absolute;
  top:-75px; /* same as top clip */
  left:0;
  /* top, right, bottom, left */
  clip:rect(75px,200px,225px,0px);
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I'm hoping to achieve, but the image doesn't actually scale with its containing element. If you change wrapper's width to 10%, the image doesn't shrink -- that's the thing I can't quite figure out. I think the example codepen I added might clarify things. I appreciate the attempt though! Thank you.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this with basic css. You would need JS to change the px values responsively. It would be of more use to understand why the clipping is actually necessary.

Comment: There are images uploaded by the user, that the user then manually labels. Only part of the image is useful for the labeling process, and the original image is significantly larger than the useful region. I'd like to show the user the useful region without cropping on the server side. Because of the way the rest of the layout is already implemented, it is significantly easier if I can just place the element in and pretend it's a normal image (i.e. I can't really use a fixed width/height).

Comment: Hmmm...let me think. I think you can position the bg image partly off the element (http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/bEqzf) but I'm not sure this will work quite the way you want.

Comment: I updated my codepen to be a bit more useful. If the container width is the same as the image width, my solution works fine. As soon as I make the container smaller, it breaks -- try making example 100px instead of 200px.

Comment: So will the container be a fixed size?

Comment: No, it won't. Everything is part of a fluid grid system. That's why in the example, I added in a fluid container that contained the image -- I *think* that should make any solution that works here work in a fully fluid solution, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I might have gotten something working... not 100% sure yet. See http://codepen.io/anon/pen/maCvd

Comment: Try using an actual large image: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/Fkfqz Not sure you're getting what you are after.

Comment: The padding and background positions need to be set via percentages (see my fork of yours: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/brEgz).

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying.. the region still doesn't quite stay the same.

Comment: Sorry, scratch that -- if you also add background-size: 100%; I think it works.

Comment: Cracked it...I think: http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/blJKd This takes any image and overlays and absolutely positioned div with the same bg image. At the moment the container sizes itself to the image but if you set a width on the container everything scales itself to fit.

Comment: Yeah, that looks like it should work. I think both approaches work actually -- the absolute positioning one and the padding one. The absolute positioning one might end up being significantly easier to understand. I'm going to play with this approach and ensure that it works, and if so, I'll accept it. Probably sleeping first though.

Comment: Ah, but I think the difference is that the absolute positioning approach relies on the image being in the container to set the *height*, whereas the padding approach always keeps the same aspect ratio, because padding is based on the width: http://blog.brianjohnsondesign.com/maintain-aspect-ratio-for-html-element-using-only-css-in-a-responsive-design/

Comment: To clarify, I'm not sure that the absolute positioning approach will work if the image isn't determining the container's height.